# Can't get master address from ZooKeeper. I am getting this error on Creating Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

[following is the error, i'm getting when creating the table.
ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBizN.png)

following is the error, i'm getting when creating the table.
ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null

**services running** (Image)

following is hbase-site.xml configuration-

```html
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/hadoop/supported/hbaseData</value>
  </property>
  
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
    <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
                 The port at which the clients will connect.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

there may be something wrong with **hbase.zookeeper.quorum** . You may try as showed below.

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <!__<value>localhost</value> NOT OK!-->
    <!--<value>127.0.0.1</value> NOT OK!-->
    <!--<value>192.168.31.66</value> OK!-->
    <value>zss</value> 
</property>
```

and zss is the hostname of my MAC!